# Error when trying to delete some elements of an array (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to delete some elements from array this way:

```
a = [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(a[i], i)
  if (a[i] > 20):
    a = np.delete(a, i)
print(a)
```

And I catch an error: *index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5*. I don't really understand what's wrong with the code above. Could somebody, please, explain the problem?

Comment: You're trying to perform *numpy* operation on regular list, is this ok?

Comment: Have you looked at `a` as it changes in the loop?  You print `a[i]` but not `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this list: `[1,2,3]`
When the second element is deleted, you get: `[1,3]`

When traversing the list left-to-right, removing elements changes the index of the rest of the list. So, when you want to remove the `3`, you must remove the second element, not the third.

Solution: traverse the list right-to-left.

Answer (score 1):

List length varies by removing elements. You need to track the original list in loop. In the following sample I kept the original elements of the list and applied the change in a copied one.

```
a = [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
b = a[:]
for i in a:
  if (i > 20):
      b.remove(i)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying numpy operations on regular list, also still if you use `.pop()`, you will delete items while iterating list, so use another list and assign slice copy of it:

```
a = [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
n = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(a[i], i)
  if (a[i] < 20):
    n.append(a[i])
a = n[:]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

so, you deleted the [30] element from the list, your list the last index will be 4, then you will access a[5] -> error!

```
a = [2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40]
a2 = []
for i in a:
  print(i)
  if (i <= 20):
    a2.append(i)
print(a2)
```

output

```
2
5
10
20
30
40
[2, 5, 10, 20]
```